# using @each with @mixins

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I need to write 144 @mixins. To avoid that i am trying to use @each in SCSS.

This is my code:

```
$line-heights: (
  text-4xs: $line-height-4xs,
  text-3xs: $line-height-3xs,
  text-2xs: $line-height-2xs,
  text-xs: $line-height-xs,
  text-sm: $line-height-sm,
  text-base: $line-height-base,
  text-xl: $line-height-xl,
  text-2xl: $line-height-2xl,
  text-3xl: $line-height-3xl,
  text-4xl: $line-height-4xl,
  text-5xl: $line-height-5xl,
  text-6xl: $line-height-6xl,
  text-7xl: $line-height-7xl,
  text-8xl: $line-height-8xl,
  text-9xl: $line-height-9xl
);

$font-sizes: (
  text-4xs: $font-size-4xs,
  text-3xs: $font-size-3xs,
  text-2xs: $font-size-2xs,
  text-xs: $font-size-xs,
  text-sm: $font-size-sm,
  text-base: $font-size-base,
  text-xl: $font-size-xl,
  text-2xl: $font-size-2xl,
  text-3xl: $font-size-3xl,
  text-4xl: $font-size-4xl,
  text-5xl: $font-size-5xl,
  text-6xl: $font-size-6xl,
  text-7xl: $font-size-7xl,
  text-8xl: $font-size-8xl,
  text-9xl: $font-size-9xl
);

$font-weights: (
  font-line: 100,
  font-extralight: 200,
  font-light: 300,
  font-medium: 500,
  font-semibold: 600,
  font-bold: 700,
  font-extrabold: 800,
  font-black: 900
);

@each $line-height-name, $line-height in $line-heights {
  @each $font-weight-name, $weight-value in $font-weights {
    $mixin-name: unquote("#{$line-height-name}-#{$font-weight-name}");

    @mixin #{$mixin-name} {
      font-size: map-get($font-sizes, $line-height-name);
      line-height: $line-height;
      font-weight: $weight-value;
    }
  }
}
```

So, as you can see i have 3 group of styles and i am trying to create @mixins with them.

I tried a couple of variations generaly and common errors are:

Expected Identifier error or I am not able to use my @mixins created in @each

Answer (score 0):

You can make your all variables in a mixin just like this.........

```css
@mixin mixin_name($font_size: 1rem){
      font-size: $font_size; //$font_size take the font size as a parameter
    }
```

Identical you can make many mixin and pass your font size or line height as a parameter. When you use the mixin anywhere you can pass your font size as you wise and if you won't send any font size it's set a default font size of 1 rem. That's it uses the mixin like this and uses it anywhere and sends any value to it as a parameter and the value-based worked it.